# Best way to prevent SQL Injection when preparing statement is impossible

Tags: php, sql-injection

I have to work on an old site with major security issues : SQL Injections are really easy to perform.

Obviously, the best way to prevent this kind of attacks is to escape what is used in query (prepare statements with PDO, mysql_real_escape_string with MySql, etc.) but we can't do that quickly : the whole site is procedural PHP (no class), the queries are "prepared" everywhere, there are hundreds of pages and thousands of users everyday, and a new version wil come as soon as possible.

So since this morning the following function is called on each request to detect suspicious POST or GET parameters based on keywords.

```
const SQLI_UNSAFE = 3;
const SQLI_WARNING = 2;
const SQLI_SAFE = 1;
const SQLI_MAIL_DEST = 'monmail@mondest.com'; 

function sqlicheck() {

    $params = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
    $is_warning = false;

    foreach($params as $key=>$param) {
        switch(getSafeLevel($param)) {
            case SQLI_SAFE: 
                break;
            case SQLI_WARNING:
                $is_warning = true;
                break;
            case SQLI_UNSAFE: 
                mail(SQLI_MAIL_DEST, 'SQL INJECTION ATTACK', print_r($_REQUEST, true).' '.print_r($_SERVER, true));     
                header('Location: http://monsite/404.php');
                exit();     
            }

    }

    if($is_warning === true) {
        mail(SQLI_MAIL_DEST, 'SQL INJECTION WARNING', print_r($_REQUEST, true).print_r($_SERVER, true));
    }
}
function getSafeLevel($param) {

    $error_words  = array('select%20','drop%20','delete%20','truncate%20','insert%20','%20tbclient','select ','drop ','delete ','truncate ','insert ',);
    $warning_words = array('%20','select','drop','delete','truncate', ';','union');


    foreach($error_words as $error_word) {
        if(stripos($param, $error_word) !== false) return SQLI_UNSAFE;  
    }
    foreach($warning_words as $warning_word) {
        if(stripos($param, $warning_word) !== false) return SQLI_WARNING;   
    }

    return SQLI_SAFE; 
}
```

This seems to detect some kinds of attacks but it's clearly very basic. Any ideas to improve it? Any major issue ?

Comment: What's the purpose, to fix where injections are attempted?

Comment: Exactly : the purpose is to detect where and maybe who, to correct it immediatly if there is any risk, and if we are sure to redirect the hacker to 404.

Comment: You should also include a safe word, it's 'banana'.

Comment: @PMV : I have to find a quick response to a real problem

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that the database user executing the queries only has select, update, delete permissions. If the user can't execute drop, there's no way it'll happen (this assumes that your users will never need to create or drop tables, but if they do, you can create table level permissions to protect the big tables).

Second, your script will only tell you what people are using; it won't do a site wide check of what queries are possible; if there's a section of your site that isn't used much, you won't get any mail telling you. Better to just comb through the code with a search tool.

After that, you have to start modifying the code and doing escaping and validation, and that's just going to take a while.

Comment: I agree : we check the database user permissions, but I don't understand your second argument as the goal is to prevent most of attacks and to be aware of a new attacks. Finally, I can't just quickly modify the whole code because of lot of black magic and no test case.

Comment: What I meant with the second argument is that your users aren't evenly testing all features of your site. You'll get a bunch of mail on the most frequently used parts and very little or even none on the unused parts, but the unknown parts are just as vulnerable. So this method will help you find most of the attacks, but not all of them, and once you've gotten mail and have time to address it, it may be too late.

Comment: Also, if your site allows people to type text, they're going to be disappointed when they use select, update, delete, and drop in legitimate ways. Perhaps instead of exiting and redirecting you could do a replace on the words to make them slightly different but not those words. Like replace select with choose, update with change, etc. Or take them back to where they were and present an error message telling them what they can do different.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `real_escape_string()` `htmlentities()` stripslashes and filter classes of php and log the SQL queries so that you can see what people are sending you, use sha256 with some md5 you will be ok other thing is for quick action just send login data in binary format